# не работет парсер на питоне

Tags: python

Выдаёт пустой список если использовать find_all()

Или выдаёт None если использовать find()

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
url = 'https://cache-kirov.ru/?cat=00000001#productList'
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")
nuj = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'toproduct')
print(nuj)
```

Comment: По коду все верно результат выдает.

Comment: на странице нет ни одного div с классом toproduct, есть только 'a' с таким классом. Но вы то ищете именно div ...